# Blinking moon of death since SSD upgrade on standby

Tags: power-management, suspend, ssd, standby

I own a Lenovo SL510 (4G RAM) and I just upgraded it with a Samsung 840 Evo 120G.

Previously I was using Ubuntu. Later on I switched to Linux Mint Nadia. At the very beginning (Ubuntu 10.10 I guess) I remember having problems getting my system into suspend to RAM. But this vanished with 11.04. I am using 14.04 now.

After the SSD upgrade the problem occurs again. I set my notebook to standby using either `FN + F4`, `sudo pm-suspend` or the menu. All three fail with the same symptom:

- LCD goes black (even backlight)
- Fan stays powered
- Power-LED blinks ("blinking moon of death")

I cannot recover the Notebook from standby. I have to kill it by pressing 5s the Power button.

The weird thing is that it doesn't occur always. **In about 20% of cases standby works as expected.** Patterns observed:

- immediately after power-up a standby never works
- if after standby-ing the logon-screen appears, standby **always** works
- but sometimes standby works also without a visible logon-screen
- after standby worked first time during a session, it's not guaranteed but more likely to work again

So to all the Sherlock Holmes out there: I'm sure the problem can be fixed!

There are many forum entries for this very particular topic but none had a working solution. I already tried debugging and fixing this on various ways but I was not fortunate. What I want to do now is a focused search for the error.

I will start with posting log-messages and debugging steps in the comments.

Comment: Successful standby (notebook ran already some hours)

syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758148/

pm-suspend-log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758151/

running applications: chromium, terminal

Comment: Another Succesful standby (notebook ran already some hours) syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758172/ pm-suspend-log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758175/ running applications: chromium, terminal. I can go on and on in this session, standby always works, also with different running applications. Going to restart now.

Comment: unsuccesful standby (immediately after startup) syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758183/ pm-suspend-log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758186/ I recognized in the syslog that not all startup-processes were finished (e.g. cups)

Comment: succesful standby (3min after startup, locked the screen, wait until black, unlock screen, enter standby). syslog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758203/ pm-suspend-log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7758205/

Comment: things that did not work: "quirk-mode standby" as suggested here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=65818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this solution is working:

1. install uswsusp using: `sudo apt-get install uswsusp`
2. start standby using `sudo s2ram -f -a 1`

Solution found here (similar problem): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94735/linuxmint15-suspend-to-ram-not-working

Disk encryption is also in use here, so perhaps this is the crucial thing.

I am interested in making this my default suspend application on all shortcuts (closing the lid, fn + f4 etc) - still searching on a solution for this one (the /etc/pm/config.d/anything-stuff doesn't work)

edit: even this solution won't work in any case :-( I am frustrated.